# Keep the right type while assigning value to a cell

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I want to initiate a worksheet with a JavaScript object which looks like `{ "A1:B2": [["01", "02"], ["03", "04"]], "C5": [[4]] }`, I have the following code:

```
function sheetIni(data) {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var range = sheet.getRange(key);
                range.values = newData;
            };
        }
        return ctx.sync().then(function () {
            console.log("done")
        })
    })
};
```

I realise that the result in the worksheet turns out to be respectively `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` in `A1`, `B1`, `A2`, `B2`; it converts automatically a string to a number (eg, `"02"` to `2`).

Does anyone know how to avoid this automatic conversion?

In general, how could I make sure a javascript value can be faithfully assigned to a cell value without extra conversion?

Answer (score 3):

The safest thing to do, when assigning data to arbitrary cells, is to set **number formatting first**, and then the value.

For text strings, the "@" number format serves as a way of declaring "I want this cell to contain a text string, even if it comes in as a number".  It's the same as the user entering values into Excel manually.

For future reference: if you want a working code snippet back, the easiest way of ensuring it is to first *create and share a snippet* using [Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import) and share a link to it in the question.  That way, it would be very easy for someone like myself to import the code, make a quick tweak, and send you a final snippet back.

Comment: My tests show that, for a big array of values, if we make an array of numberFormats (eg, `[["@", null], ["@", null], ..., ["@", null]]`), the assignment takes time. `range.numberFormat = "@"` is fast, but it makes the entire range `string`. Additionally, when users enter manually a number in Excel, I think it is considered as `number` rather than `string`...

Comment: Do you have any trick to keep the original type while assigning, and do not slow it very much?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to prepend numbers that you want to be treated as text with a '

[["'01", "02"], ["'03", 4]]

will result in excel
[["01", 2], ["03", 4]]

This avoids having to format cells as Text (which can have nasty side effects)

When retrieving an array of values from Excel you can load types as well as values and then loop the array prepending text numbers with ' before sending the array back to Excel.